# Fix orientation of screen on tablet and phone

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-2.0.0

in my cordova application , I fix orientation in config.xml like :

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"/>
```

this works fine for tablet.

now, I need to fix it to portrait if device width < 767px

so : for tablet the view will be landscape and for phone in portait.

do you have any idea to fix it ?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to vary orientation on Android based on detected device width, you'll need to do this when the app is running, so you'll need to remove the orientation preference from the config.xml. 
You can use the [cordova-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) plugin to set the device orientation from within your app, something like:

```
var MAX_WIDTH = 767;
$(document).on("deviceready", function(){
    if($(window).width() < MAX_WIDTH || $(window).height() < MAX_WIDTH){
        screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
    }else{
        screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
    }
});
```

Using pixel dimensions to determine whether a device is a tablet is not very robust - newer Android phones with high-resolution screens will report screen widths > 767px. 
So maybe consider using using [phonegap-istablet](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-istablet) plugin to determine if the device is a tablet:

```
$(document).on("deviceready", function(){
    if(window.isTablet){
        screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
    }else{
        screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
    }
});
```

Comment: that's exactly what I looking for. thank you @DaveAlden

Comment: I know this is old, but the changes of orientation will apply when the app is ready. Is there a way to set it on app start? Setting it in config.xml?